# Wordpress query parameters and blank page

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Recently links with query parameters on my wordpress website stopped working. They now just return blanks pages. However the same links without query parameters works fine. 
Example: 
https://www.example.com/signup/?Subscription=3 - returns blank page
https://www.example.com/signup - works fine

What can be the problem and what are the ways to solve it?

Comment: Perhaps you could turn on PHP error reporting (errors, warning, notices, etc.) and see what you get. There's probably a PHP error (maybe a failed database connection) that is hidden from you because your server is set to production level, with all errors hidden.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the answer. I turn on debug mode on worpress and also turn on displaying errors at php.ini file. But still all I get is blank page without any signs of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick check, make sure you refresh your permalinks by visiting Settings > Reading > Permalinks in your control panel.

If this doesn't help, see below.

I'd start by doing standard WordPress diagnostics. That is, disable all plugins. If it doesn't work still, try switching to a default theme.

If it still doesn't work after that, I would say that it is either a problem with your `.htaccess` file if it has been modified (by yourself or a plugin), or it's a problem with your web stack. If you're sure it's neither, then it may be a faulty WordPress install, or a bug within the core.

If it breaks without plugins but works when you swap themes, it's a problem with your theme.

If it works without plugins without switching themes, it's a problem with a plugin. Try testing it by enabling them one at a time and attempting to repeat the issue.

Without more information / context, there's not a lot more I can do to help isolate where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't know why, but WP Fastest Cache caused it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).